# Finding the equation of a rational function from a set of points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, systems-of-equations, curves, nonlinear-system

I want to fit a curve onto a set of points. The curve should look like a log or square root function.I want the function to be specifically in this format (per the requirements of my supervisor):

> $\frac{ax}{b+x}$

The set of points are: (1,65), (200,70), (800,75)

What I did was use two of the points to build a system of equations and solve for a and b. The function I come up with passes through the points but has oscillations in between the points and does not have the shape of a log/square root function. I was recommended to use Lineweaver-Burke plot to deal with this problem. I did some reading on the subject but could not manage to understand how I can use this in this instance.

Any advice on how to fit a rational function for the set of points provided is appreciated.

Comment: What equation did you get? It seems two points are sufficient to find $a$ and $b$ in this case.

Comment: Are you sure that the first point is not $(1\color{red}{00},65$ ?

Comment: Yes @ClaudeLeibovici

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me address the general problem where you have $n$ data points $(x_i,y_i)$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,n$ and you want to fit, in the least square sense, the model
$$y=\frac {a x}{b+x}$$ which is nonlinear (because of $b$). So, at a time, nonlinear regression will be required which means that "reasonable" estimates will need to be provided.

You can have these *estimates* writing
$$\frac 1 y=\frac b a \frac 1 x+\frac 1 a$$ So, in a first step, define $t_i=\frac 1 {x_i}$ and $z_i=\frac 1 {y_i}$ making the model to be 
$$z=\alpha t+\beta$$ and a basic linear regression will give $(\alpha,\beta)$ from which the *estimates* $a_*=\frac 1 \beta$ and $b_*=\frac \alpha \beta$.

But, since what is measured is $y$ and not any of its possible tranforms, nonlinear regression will consist in the minimization of
$$SSQ=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac {a x_i}{b+x_i}-y_i \right)^2$$ If you do not access a nonlinear regression software, compute the partial derivatives of $SSQ$
$$\frac{\partial SSQ}{\partial a}=2\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {x_i\left(\frac {a x_i}{b+x_i}-y_i \right)}{b+x_i}\tag 1$$
$$\frac{\partial SSQ}{\partial b}=-2a\sum_{i=1}^n\frac {x_i\left(\frac {a x_i}{b+x_i}-y_i \right)}{(b+x_i)^2}\tag 2$$

Setting these derivatives equal to $0$, $(1)$ gives
$$a(b)=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n  \frac {x_i y_i}{b+x_i} } {\sum_{i=1}^n\frac {x^2_i}{(b+x_i)^2} } \tag 3$$ and your are left with the equation (from $(2)$)
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac {x_i\left(a(b)\frac { x_i}{b+x_i}-y_i \right)}{(b+x_i)^2}=0\tag 4$$ which can be solved using graphics or Newton method for example since you already have the starting point $b_*$.

Answer (score 5):

Caution: As Claude Leibovici's comment says, this is only good for obtaining *estimates* of $(a,b)$ for $y$.

Let $y=\frac{ax}{b+x}$. Then for some input $x$ and output $y$ we have 
\begin{align}
\frac{ax}{b+x} &= y\\
ax-by&=xy
\end{align}

If we want to fit the points $(1,65),(200,70),$ and $(800,75)$ we can set up the following system of $3$ equations and $2$ unknowns:

\begin{align}
a-65b &= 65\\
200x-70b &= 14000\\
800x-75b &= 60000\\
\end{align}

We can rewrite this in the form of the matrix equation $Ax=b$ as

$$\pmatrix{1 & -65\\ 200 & -70\\ 800 & -75}\pmatrix{a\\b} = \pmatrix{65\\14000\\60000}$$

which does not have a solution. However, we can find a least squares approximation by solving $A^TAx=A^Tb$. I went ahead and did the computation in MATLAB, yielding 
\begin{align}
a &\approx 75.5 \\
b &\approx 7.31 
\end{align}
Here is a picture of the curve in black with the points in red.
[image: Plot of least squares estimated curve.]

This is about as far as my knowledge extends. Perhaps someone can comment further on whether or not this is a good fit (looking at things such as residuals). Click [here](http://math.mit.edu/~gs/linearalgebra/ila0403.pdf) or [here](http://global.oup.com/booksites/content/0199268010/samplesec3) for some readings I quickly found through google.

Comment: If I may suggest, be careful : your approach is good for getting *estimates* of $(a,b)$ but remember that what is measured is $y$ and not any of its possible trandorms.